# How to write a mathematics problem book

Tags: templates, book-design

I'm a mathematics student and a newbie latex-user, and would start to collect my favourite problems in a problem book written in latex, dividing the content in two parts: the first, with the labeled problems, with the source of the problems, the origin et cetera; the second part, with the respective solutions. 
Obviously I would do my best, with the two parts hyperlinked and an index, aiming to create a good document for others students.

I have yet no idea how to do it in a pretty and efficent way.

I'm looking for a template, a similar .tex document where to see how to do it without having to read a lot of manuals.
Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: Will the accepted answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924313/creating-problem-sets-with-answers-in-latex work for you?

Comment: Here's another related question: [How can I produce exercises in one part of a LaTeX document with selected answers in another?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/301/1235)

Comment: Is this a dupe of the question Hendrik has linked to? Seems to cover similar ground to me.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the package probsoln by Nicola Talbot? I think it is exactly what you need. You can find it  in CTAN. If I'm not wrong, it's distributed with MikTeX. There is, also, an article about it in the last issue of the PracTeX journal (if you don't know the journal, there is a link from the TUG page (http://www.tug.org)). I use frequently this package to prepare homework or tests for my students and, yes, also to prepare a problem book.

Best luck!

Comment: Many thanks for the suggested package and journal, I'll try it!

Answer (score 2):

I have elaborated my own answers2 package for my textbook. It is made from [answers.sty](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/answers) and provides hyperlinks as you need. I could share my code with you but I am too lasy to put it on ctan.

Comment: Then it is possible to get it in another way?

Comment: @anatematic: kia999 at mail dot ru

Comment: Advertising packages which are not generally available does not really help to answer a question, in general. Submitting to CTAN is not so hard, and if you've got useful code then it would be a great service to the community to send it.