# Math book: how to write Exercise and Answers

Tags: books, exercises, mathematics

EDIT
within `\documentclass[12pt]{book}`I want to create chapter-wise exercises and put all the solutions (with or without hints) at the end of the book.

I want to do this in simple and non-tedious way like: For the input of the questions, I just want to add `\question`for each question and similar for answer, but all the answer should come at the end of the book.

> I need the Exercises No as 1.1, 1.2, ..., 2.1, 2.2, ....
>
> Problem Nos as 1, 2, 3, ...
>
> The answer should include page No of the exercise as given in the attached jpg file.

**Exercise style:**

[image]

**Solution type:**

[image]

A MWE is as follows (I also don't know how to write solution in chapter 2 as problems are written within `\begin{minipage} \end{minipage}`. Suppose all solutions are: This is a solution Ex **No.**)

```
    \documentclass[12pt,openany,twoside]{book} 
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[thmmarks,standard,thref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{answers}

\theoremseparator{.}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{pro}{Problem}[chapter]

\Newassociation{loigiai}{Answer}{loigiaichung}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Firist }
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Opensolutionfile{loigiaichung}[pro]
In problem 1-3, determine whether the given differential equation is separable 
\begin{pro}
$\frac{dy}{dx}-\sin{(x+y)}=0$
\begin{loigiai}
This is a solution of Ex 1
\end{loigiai}
\end{pro}

\begin{pro}
$\frac{dy}{dx}=4y^2-3y+1$
\begin{loigiai}
This is a solution of Ex 2
\end{loigiai}
\end{pro}


\begin{pro}
$\frac{ds}{dt}=t\ln{(s^{2t})}+8t^2$
\begin{loigiai}
This is a solution Ex 3
\end{loigiai}
\end{pro}

In problem 4-6, solve the equation 
\begin{pro}
$\frac{dx}{dt}=3xt^2$
\begin{loigiai}
This is a solution Ex 4
\end{loigiai}
\end{pro}

\begin{pro}
$y^{-1}dy+ye^{\cos{x}}\sin{x}dx=0$
\begin{loigiai}
This is a solution Ex 5
\end{loigiai}
\end{pro}


\begin{pro}
$(x+xy^2)dx+ye^{\cos{x}}\sin{x}dx=0$
\begin{loigiai}
This is a solution Ex 5
\end{loigiai}
\end{pro}

\begin{pro}
$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{y}{t+1} + 4t^2 +  4t$, $\quad$ $y(1) = 10$
\begin{loigiai}
This is a solution Ex 6
\end{loigiai}
\end{pro}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\chapter{Second }
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{pro}
Eight systems of differential equations and five direction fields are given below.  Determine the system that corresponds to each direction field and sketch the solution curves that correspond to the initial conditions $(x_0, y_0) = (0,1)$ and $(x_0, y_0) = (1,-1)$.
\begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
$(i)$\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{dt} & = -x \\
\frac{dy}{dt} & = y-1\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
$(ii)$\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{dt} & = x^2 - 1 \\
\frac{dy}{dt} & = y\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
$(iii)$\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{dt} & = x+2y \\
\frac{dy}{dt} & = -y\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
$(iv)$\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{dt} & = 2x \\
\frac{dy}{dt} & =  y\end{align*}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
$(v)$\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{dt} & = x \\
\frac{dy}{dt}  & = 2y\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
$(vi)$\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{dt} & = x-1 \\
\frac{dy}{dt} & = -y\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
$(vii)$\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{dt} & = x^2-1 \\
\frac{dy}{dt} & = -y\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
$(viii)$\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{dt} & = x- 2y \\
\frac{dy}{dt} & =  -y\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\end{pro}
\chapter{Answer to all problems}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Closesolutionfile{loigiaichung}
\section{This is solution}
\input{pro}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There are whole document classes and styles devoted to this... A search of this site would help, I am sure.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Would you suggest any one fit with my requirement please.

Comment: I am sorry, but it is not my specialty, though I recall seeing regular questions on it.  The `exsheets` package comes to mind.

Comment: ... and `answers`, `exams`, `probsoln` etc....

Comment: There is also `exercise` package.

Comment: And if none of the available packages are pretty enough, it isn't that difficult to create your own environments, counters, etc.

Comment: I am really a lay man in this subject. Would you please help

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301/how-can-i-produce-exercises-in-one-part-of-a-latex-document-with-selected-answer and http://ctan.org/topic/exercise

Comment: Also related: [Assignments and Examinations](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/exams.shtml)

Comment: I am not very efficient to use latex. Please give me a suitable latex format that fits with the jpg that I have attached.

Comment: I think you need to do the first step. Look at the packages, read threw their documentation, pick what is best suited and then work on a MWE like you did with your last question. Give us some code to play with. But If you just post a picture and say: "Do this very complicated thing for me." then you probably won't get an answers.

Comment: @Georg I have given a MWE. Please help me make in nice as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here is a solution with `exercise` package.

Its option `answerdelayed` allows you to print the answer where you want with `\shipoutAnswer`.

`lastexercise` means that if you don't put anything as answer reference, the `Answer` environment is referred to the previous exercise. However, I have also put `\begin{Answer}[ref={...}]`, in this way you can move the code for the answers where you want, but you have to keep the order. For how I have created the code for the first answer of the chapter (to print `CHAPTER ...` in the final list), you also have to write it within the relative chapter.

Moreover, To have `CHAPTER ...` printed in the final answer list, you have to set `\setboolean{firstanswerofthechapter}{true}` at the beginning and `\setboolean{firstanswerofthechapter}{false}` at the end of the first answer of a chapter (maybe there's a smarter way to do it but it's above my level of knowledge).

Eventually, if you need horizontal lists you have to use `tasks` environment, otherwise, the ordinary `\Question` is enough I put an example of both in my MWE.

*Edit:* I've changed the numbering as required by the OP in their comment.

If you want the roman numbers to begin from i. in the second question, just remove the `[resume=true]` option.

*Second edit:* To have the list of the second exercise correctly aligned, you have to use `aligned` instead of `align*`. Since these are systems, maybe it's better to put a curly bracket before, like here in Ex. 2.2:

*Third edit:* In the original post I wrote `counter-format={tsk[r].}` as an option of the `tasks` package.
But, since October 2019, that option is deprecated.  Hence, the current version has `label=\roman*.`.
Thanks to EthanAlvaree for pointing it out.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{firstanswerofthechapter}  

\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{lightcyan}{cyan!40!white}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\usepackage{tasks}
\newlength{\longestlabel}
\settowidth{\longestlabel}{\bfseries viii.}
\settasks{label=\roman*., label-format={\bfseries}, label-width=\longestlabel,
item-indent=0pt, label-offset=2pt, column-sep={10pt}}

\usepackage[lastexercise,answerdelayed]{exercise}
\counterwithin{Exercise}{chapter}
\counterwithin{Answer}{chapter}
\renewcounter{Exercise}[chapter]
\newcommand{\QuestionNB}{\bfseries\arabic{Question}.\ }
\renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{EXERCISES}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{\noindent\def\stackalignment{l}% code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195118/101651
    \stackunder[0pt]{\colorbox{cyan}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{\LARGE\ExerciseHeaderNB\;\large\ExerciseName}}}}{\textcolor{lightcyan}{\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}}}\medskip}
\renewcommand{\AnswerName}{Exercises}
\renewcommand{\AnswerHeader}{\ifthenelse{\boolean{firstanswerofthechapter}}%
    {\bigskip\noindent\textcolor{cyan}{\textbf{CHAPTER \thechapter}}\newline\newline%
        \noindent\bfseries\emph{\textcolor{cyan}{\AnswerName\ \ExerciseHeaderNB, page %
                \pageref{\AnswerRef}}}\smallskip}
    {\noindent\bfseries\emph{\textcolor{cyan}{\AnswerName\ \ExerciseHeaderNB, page \pageref{\AnswerRef}}}\smallskip}}
\setlength{\QuestionIndent}{16pt}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{First}
    
    \begin{Exercise}\label{EX11}
        \vspace{-\baselineskip}% <-- You don't need this line of code if there's some text here
        \Question In problem \ref{EX11-1-i}-\ref{EX11-1-iii}, determine whether the given differential equation is separable  
        \begin{tasks}(2)
            \task\label{EX11-1-i} $\frac{dy}{dx}-\sin{(x+y)}=0$     
            \task $\frac{dy}{dx}=4y^2-3y+1$ 
            \task\label{EX11-1-iii} $\frac{ds}{dt}=t\ln{(s^{2t})}+8t^2$ 
        \end{tasks}
        \Question In problem \ref{EX11-2-iv}-\ref{EX11-2-viii}, solve the equation 
        \begin{tasks}[resume=true](2)
            \task\label{EX11-2-iv} $\frac{dx}{dt}=3xt^2$
            \task $y^{-1}dy+ye^{\cos{x}}\sin{x}dx=0$
            \task $(x+xy^2)dx+ye^{\cos{x}}\sin{x}dx=0$
            \task\label{EX11-2-viii} $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{y}{t+1} + 4t^2 +  4t$, $\quad$ $y(1) = 10$
        \end{tasks}
    \end{Exercise}
    \setboolean{firstanswerofthechapter}{true}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{Answer}[ref={EX11}]
            \Question 
            \begin{tasks}
                \task This is a solution of Ex 1
                \task This is a solution of Ex 2 
                \task This is a solution of Ex 3 
            \end{tasks} 
            \Question 
            \begin{tasks}[resume=true]
                \task This is a solution of Ex 4
                \task This is a solution of Ex 5 
                \task This is a solution of Ex 6 
                \task This is a solution of Ex 7 
            \end{tasks} 
        \end{Answer}
    \end{multicols}
    \setboolean{firstanswerofthechapter}{false}
    
    \begin{Exercise}\label{EX12}
        Another exercise. 
        \Question If you don't need a horizontal list, you can simply use \verb|\Question|
    \end{Exercise}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{Answer}[ref={EX12}]
            \Question This is a solution of Ex 1
        \end{Answer}
    \end{multicols}
    
    \chapter{Second}
    
    \begin{Exercise}\label{EX21}
        \vspace{-\baselineskip}% <-- You don't need this line of code if there's some text here
        \Question Eight systems of differential equations and five direction fields are given below.  Determine the system that corresponds to each direction field and sketch the solution curves that correspond to the initial conditions $(x_0, y_0) = (0,1)$ and $(x_0, y_0) = (1,-1)$.
        \begin{tasks}(3)
            \task $\begin{aligned}
            \frac{dx}{dt} & = -x \\     
            \frac{dy}{dt} & = y-1
            \end{aligned}$
            \task $\begin{aligned}
            \frac{dx}{dt} & = x^2 - 1 \\        
            \frac{dy}{dt} & = y
            \end{aligned}$
            \task $\begin{aligned}
            \frac{dx}{dt} & = x+2y \\
            \frac{dy}{dt} & = -y
            \end{aligned}$
            \task $\begin{aligned}
            \frac{dx}{dt} & = 2x \\
            \frac{dy}{dt} & =  y
            \end{aligned}$
            \task $\begin{aligned}
            \frac{dx}{dt} & = x \\
            \frac{dy}{dt}  & = 2y
            \end{aligned}$ 
            \task$\begin{aligned}
            \frac{dx}{dt} & = x-1 \\
            \frac{dy}{dt} & = -y
            \end{aligned}$
            \task$\begin{aligned}
            \frac{dx}{dt} & = x^2-1 \\
            \frac{dy}{dt} & = -y
            \end{aligned}$        
            \task $\begin{aligned}
            \frac{dx}{dt} & = x- 2y \\
            \frac{dy}{dt} & =  -y
            \end{aligned}$
        \end{tasks}
    \end{Exercise}
    \setboolean{firstanswerofthechapter}{true}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{Answer}[ref={EX21}]
            \Question 
            \begin{tasks}
                \task This is a solution of Ex 1
                \task This is a solution of Ex 2 
                \task This is a solution of Ex 3 
                \task This is a solution of Ex 4 
                \task This is a solution of Ex 5 
                \task This is a solution of Ex 6 
                \task This is a solution of Ex 7 
                \task This is a solution of Ex 8 
            \end{tasks}
        \end{Answer}
    \end{multicols}
    \setboolean{firstanswerofthechapter}{false}
    \newpage        
    \begin{Exercise}\label{EX22}
        Since these are systems, maybe it's better to put the \verb|aligned| enviroment within  \verb|\left\{| and \verb|\right.|: 
        \Question Eight systems of differential equations and five direction fields are given below.  Determine the system that corresponds to each direction field and sketch the solution curves that correspond to the initial conditions $(x_0, y_0) = (0,1)$ and $(x_0, y_0) = (1,-1)$.
        \begin{tasks}(3)
            \task $\left\{\begin{aligned}
            \frac{dx}{dt} & = -x \\     
            \frac{dy}{dt} & = y-1
            \end{aligned}\right.$
            \task $\left\{\begin{aligned}
            \frac{dx}{dt} & = x^2 - 1 \\        
            \frac{dy}{dt} & = y
            \end{aligned}\right.$
            \task $\left\{\begin{aligned}
            \frac{dx}{dt} & = x+2y \\
            \frac{dy}{dt} & = -y
            \end{aligned}\right.$
            \task $\left\{\begin{aligned}
            \frac{dx}{dt} & = 2x \\
            \frac{dy}{dt} & =  y
            \end{aligned}\right.$
            \task $\left\{\begin{aligned}
            \frac{dx}{dt} & = x \\
            \frac{dy}{dt}  & = 2y
            \end{aligned}\right.$ 
            \task$\left\{\begin{aligned}
            \frac{dx}{dt} & = x-1 \\
            \frac{dy}{dt} & = -y
            \end{aligned}\right.$
            \task $\left\{\begin{aligned}
            \frac{dx}{dt} & = x^2-1 \\
            \frac{dy}{dt} & = -y
            \end{aligned}\right.$        
            \task $\left\{\begin{aligned}
            \frac{dx}{dt} & = x- 2y \\
            \frac{dy}{dt} & =  -y
            \end{aligned}\right.$
        \end{tasks}
    \end{Exercise}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{Answer}[ref={EX22}]
            \Question 
            \begin{tasks}
                \task This is a solution of Ex 1
                \task This is a solution of Ex 2 
                \task This is a solution of Ex 3 
                \task This is a solution of Ex 4 
                \task This is a solution of Ex 5 
                \task This is a solution of Ex 6 
                \task This is a solution of Ex 7 
                \task This is a solution of Ex 8 
            \end{tasks}
        \end{Answer}
    \end{multicols}
    
    \chapter{Answer to all problems}
    
    \begin{multicols}{2}\raggedcolumns
        \shipoutAnswer
    \end{multicols}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How can I get a link from solutions back to the questions and a link from questions to the solutions.

Comment: @CarLaTeX No problem. I shall wait.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thank you very much. This is what I am requesting. In 2.1 EXERCISES subquestions of question number 1 are badly arranged. How to arrange them nicely i.e $\frac{dx}{dt}$ starts in the same line of (i) etc.

Comment: @CarLaTeX  Nice answer. How can add points or marks and total points for a particular question (`\Question`) to questions and have them align to the right like `\numpoints` in the exam package

Comment: Is there any way to print answer of just some questions? 
such in Exercise 1.1 I want to print just question 2's answer in chapter 3

Comment: @SoyebJim Of course, I think it's possible but not so simple, please ask a new question

Comment: Very nice solution. I tried it in my project but had to change `counter-format={tsk[r].}` to `label=\roman*.` instead. See this question based on the error: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602947/make-exercises-package-compatible-with-kaobook

Comment: @EthanAlvaree Corrected, thank you!

Comment: Can we classify the solution of exercises and examples by this package? Thank you!

Comment: @NamTranLe If you intend to mark the difficulty of an exercise by a certain amount of stars (or other symbols), you may use `\marker`. See Section 2.5 of the package documentation.

Comment: @CarLaTeX There are many kinds of exercises. For example, problem, exercise. One environment has each Answer environment. Command \shipoutAnswer will include all answer. I want the classifed answers.

Comment: @NamTranLe You can define a different type of exercise, for example problem. But if you want to print before all the exercise answers and then all the problem answers, I don't think it's possible with this package.

Comment: @CarLaTeX. Thank you! Use collect package and create some different types of environments. The answers can be classified. But I have trouble with the exercises numbers.

Comment: @NamTranLe Please ask a question on the main site with a minimal example. I'm sure your problem can be solved.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thank you for your sugguestion!

Answer (score 16):

- Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10922/103046), I used the `newfile` package to write the solutions to a separate file and read them in afterwards. The import lines are:

  ```
  \newoutputstream{solutions}
  \openoutputfile{\jobname.solutions}{solutions}
  \addtostream{solutions}{...}
  \closeoutputstream{solutions}
  \input{\jobname.solutions}
  ```
- I defined two counters: `exblock` and `exquestion`. `exblock` counts the "exercises" sections, while `exquestion` counts the questions within an exercise. Through these, I can give unique labels to each question.
- An exercise section starts with the `\exheader` command. This macro includes a call of `\section`! After `\exheader`, you can type questions within an `exercises` environment using the `\question` macro. It takes two arguments: the question and the solution.

  ```
  \exheader{}
  \begin{exercises}
      \question{Question}{Answer}
  \end{exercises}
  ```
- At the end, call the macro `\printsolutions` to print the solutions to the exercises of all the chapters.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{newfile}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newoutputstream{solutions}
\openoutputfile{\jobname.solutions}{solutions}
\newcounter{exblock}
\newcounter{exquestion}
\newcounter{exsubquestion}
\newlist{questionlist}{enumerate}{1}
\newlist{solutionlist}{enumerate}{1}
\newlist{subquestionlist}{enumerate*}{1}
\newlist{subsolutionlist}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[questionlist,solutionlist]{label=\arabic*.}
\setlist[subquestionlist,subsolutionlist]{label=(\alph*),itemjoin={},before=~}
\newcommand{\exheader}{%
    \ifthenelse{\value{exblock}>0}{\addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\end{solutionlist}}}{}%
    \refstepcounter{exblock}%
    \setcounter{exquestion}{0}%
    \section{Exercises}%
    \label{ex.\arabic{exblock}}%
    \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\paragraph{Exercises \noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}}, page \noexpand\pageref{ex.\arabic{exblock}}}}%
    \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\begin{solutionlist}}%
}
\newcommand{\printsolutions}{%
    \ifthenelse{\value{exblock}>0}{\addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\end{solutionlist}}}{}%
    \closeoutputstream{solutions}%
    \input{\jobname.solutions}%
}
\newenvironment{exercises}[1][]{%
    \begin{questionlist}[start=\value{exquestion}+1, #1]%
}{%
    \end{questionlist}%
}
\newenvironment{exercisescol}[2][]{%
    \begin{multicols}{#2}%
    \begin{questionlist}[start=\value{exquestion}+1, #1]%
}{%
    \end{questionlist}%
    \end{multicols}%
}
\newcommand{\question}[2]{%
    \refstepcounter{exquestion}%
    \label{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exquestion}}%
    \item #1%
    \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\item[\noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exquestion}}.] #2}%
}
\newenvironment{subquestions}[1][]{%
    \refstepcounter{exquestion}%
    \label{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exquestion}}%
    \setcounter{exsubquestion}{0}%
    \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\item[\noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exquestion}}.]\noexpand\begin{subsolutionlist}}%
    \item #1%
    \begin{subquestionlist}%
}{%
    \end{subquestionlist}%
    \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\end{subsolutionlist}}
}
\newcommand{\subquestion}[2]{%
    \refstepcounter{exsubquestion}%
    \item #1%
    \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\item #2}%
}


\setlist*[questionlist]{font=\bfseries}
\setlist*[solutionlist]{noitemsep,font=\bfseries}
\setlist*[subquestionlist]{font=\bfseries}
\setlist*[subsolutionlist]{noitemsep,font=\bfseries,itemjoin={\\},before={}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Antidifferentiation}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-4]

\exheader
Find the indicated integral.
\begin{exercisescol}[noitemsep]{2}
    \question{$\int\sqrt{x}dx$}{$\tfrac{2}{3}x\sqrt{x}+C$}
    \question{$\int3e^xdx$}{$3e^x+C$}
    \question{$\int(3x^2-\sqrt{5x}+2)dx$}{$x^3-\tfrac{2}{3}x\sqrt{5x}+2x+C$}
    \question{$\int(\tfrac{1}{2x}-\tfrac{2}{x^2}+\tfrac{3}{\sqrt{x}})dx$}{$\tfrac{1}{2}\ln|x|+\tfrac{2}{x}+6\sqrt{x}+C$}
\end{exercisescol}
Now some more complicated questions:
\begin{exercises}
    \question{Find the function $f$ whose tangent has slope $x^3-\tfrac{2}{x^2}+2$ for each value of $x$ and whose graph passes through the point $(1,3)$.}{$f(x)=\tfrac{1}{4}x^4+\tfrac{2}{x}+2x-\tfrac{5}{4}$}
    \begin{subquestions}[Suppose a car supplies a constant deceleration of $A$ meters per second squared. If it is traveling at 90 kilometers per hour when the brakes are applied, its stopping distance is 50 meters.]
        \subquestion{What is $A$?}{$A=6.25$}
        \subquestion{What would the stopping distance have been if the car had been traveling at only 54 kilometers per hour when the brakes were applied?}{42 meters}
    \end{subquestions}
\end{exercises}

\chapter{Integration by Substitution}

\section{Method}
\lipsum[5-6]

\section{Examples}
\lipsum[7-9]

\exheader
Find the indicated integral.
\begin{exercises}
    \question{$\int(2x+6)^5dx$}{$\tfrac{1}{12}(2x+6)^6+C$}
    \question{$\int xe^{x^2}dx$}{$\tfrac{1}{2}e^{x^2}+C$}
\end{exercises}

\chapter{Appendix}

\section{Solutions}

\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

[image]

Further features:

- The `exercises` environment continues the question numbering properly, even if you interrupt it to write a hint or so.
- The `exercises` environment can take as an optional argument any [`enumitem`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10689/103046) option (like `noitemsep`) that you want to pass on to the `enumerate` environment that contains the questions. To set global options for the questions or solutions, use `\setlist*[questionlist]{...}` and `\setlist*[solutionlist]{...}`, respectively.
- You can replace the `exercises` environment by an `exercisescol` environment that takes a number as argument and calls the [`multicol`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194455/103046) environment to put the questions into columns.
- You can replace the `\question` macro by a `subquestions` environment and fill it with `\subquestion` macros (that work the same way as `\question`). `subquestions` takes as optional argument a hint that is printed before the first subquestion (only in question, not in solution):

  ```
  \begin{subquestions}[Some introductory remarks]
      \subquestion{First part}{First solution}
      \subquestion{Second part}{Second solution}
  \end{subquestions}
  ```
- Use `\usepackage{hyperref}` if you want to include links of the solutions back to the questions.

Comment: I used \usepackage{hyperref}, but I only get a link from solutions back to the questions but don't get a link from questions to th solutions. Can you help me?

Comment: That's right, I didn't implement that feature. To do this, one needs to update the `\question` macro and (1) add a label to the solution's item and (2) make the `\ref` the optional argument in the question's item.

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: Awesome answer. Is it possible to have the subquestions be multicolumned? So: 6. Question text (newline) (a) Question in column 1         (b) Question in column 2