# Collection of tasks, xsim, et al.: How to controll layout of printsolutions best way

Tags: xsim

I read [Math book: how to write Exercise and Answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369265/math-book-how-to-write-exercise-and-answers)
and ask myself: What is the best way to get a layout like this

[image]

using `xsim`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,paper=A5]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{2.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 1.5pt}% 50%/3 of original values

\usepackage[]{xsim}
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{basic}
  {\par\noindent\textsf{\IfInsideSolutionTF{\bfseries\footnotesize L}{\bfseries\footnotesize A}\GetExerciseProperty{counter}} }
  {\par}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template = basic ,
  solution/template = basic ,
  exercise/the-counter = \arabic{exercise}. ,
  print-solutions/headings = false,
  %print-solutions/section = true
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Various Tasks}

\section{Equations}
\begin{exercise}
 $(x+2)(x+3)+x^2+7y+y^2+(y-3)^2=11$
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
no solution
\end{solution}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{exercise}
  $x+2=5$
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  $x=3$
\end{solution}
\begin{exercise}
  $x+1=5$
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  $x=4$
\end{solution}
\end{multicols}

%\setcounter{exercise}{22}
\section{Term Simplifications}
\begin{exercise}
  $\dfrac{1}{a}+a$
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  $\dfrac{a^2+1}{a}$
\end{solution}

\chapter*{Solutions}
%\printsolutions
\minisec{Solutions 1.1, page 1}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\printsolutions[chapter=1,section=1]
\end{multicols}

\minisec{Solutions 1.2, Page 1}
\printsolutions[chapter=1,section=2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply use `\label`s and then `\ref` and `\pageref` them:

```
\section{Equations}\label{sec:equations}
...

\minisec{Solutions~\ref{sec:equations}, page~\pageref{sec:equations}}
...
```

---

The complete code:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,paper=A5]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{2.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 1.5pt}% 50%/3 of original values

\usepackage[]{xsim}
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{basic}
  {%
    \par\noindent
    \textsf{%
      \IfInsideSolutionTF
        {\bfseries\footnotesize L}
        {\bfseries\footnotesize A}\GetExerciseProperty{counter}} %
  }%
  {\par}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template = basic ,
  solution/template = basic ,
  exercise/the-counter = \arabic{exercise}. ,
  print-solutions/headings = false
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Various Tasks}

\section{Equations}\label{sec:equations}
\begin{exercise}
 $(x+2)(x+3)+x^2+7y+y^2+(y-3)^2=11$
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
no solution
\end{solution}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{exercise}
  $x+2=5$
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  $x=3$
\end{solution}
\begin{exercise}
  $x+1=5$
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  $x=4$
\end{solution}
\end{multicols}

\section{Term Simplifications}\label{sec:term-simplifications}
\begin{exercise}
  $\dfrac{1}{a}+a$
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  $\dfrac{a^2+1}{a}$
\end{solution}

\chapter*{Solutions}

\minisec{Solutions~\ref{sec:equations}, page~\pageref{sec:equations}}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\printsolutions[chapter=1,section=1]
\end{multicols}

\minisec{Solutions~\ref{sec:term-simplifications}, page~\pageref{sec:term-simplifications}}
\printsolutions[chapter=1,section=2]

\end{document}
```

[image]