# Create fascinating Math Homework Assignments

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, sectioning, tikz-styles, exercises

while I'm writing the following sheet of exercises of Brownian motion I can't get rid of the space that between the `\sec` and the `\exercise` which looks like this

**Update:**
**Since I use the comment of @Schrödinger's cat I was able to get rid of the gap. The trick is it suffices to remove `\vskip1cm` at the end of `\newcommand{\chap}[1]{.`
Now my question: Is there any other package that can to create the same sheet That I created with TIKZ.**

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,top=1cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=60pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb ,amsfonts,xcolor,tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\definecolor{col1}{RGB}{12, 102, 98}
\definecolor{col2}{RGB}{248, 193, 12}
\definecolor{col3}{RGB}{236, 67, 1}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[col1] (current page.north west)rectangle([shift={(1,0)}]current page.south west);
\fill[col2] (current page.north east)--++(-0.9,0)--++(0,-7.5)to[out=-60,in=180]++(0.9,-0.5)--cycle;
\node[red,rotate=90] at([shift={(-0.45,-4.7)}]current page.north east){{\Large \textbf{\sffamily MATHEMATICS}}};
\node[white,rotate=90] at([shift={(0.5,-4.7)}]current page.north west){{\Large \textbf{\sffamily Financial Mathematics}}};
\node[white,rotate=90] at([shift={(0.5,-23)}]current page.north west){{\Large \textbf{\sffamily Prof Mohcine Educ}}};   
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcounter{chpn}
\setcounter{chpn}{1}
\newcommand{\chap}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[fill=col1,rectangle ,text width=13cm,anchor=west,inner xsep=3cm,inner ysep=0.3cm](A) at([shift={(1.5,-1)}]current page.north west){{\Large \textbf{\sffamily\color{white} CHAPITER \arabic{chpn}: #1}}};  
\draw[line width=4.8pt,col1] ($(A.north west)!0.5!(A.south west)$ )--++(-2.5,0) ;
\draw[line width=4.8pt,col1] ([shift={(-0.11,0)}]$(A.north east)!0.5!(A.south east)$ )--++(1,0) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip1cm}
\newcommand{\sect}[1]{\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=white,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,colback=red!14]
\centering \textbf{#1}
    \end{tcolorbox}
 }
\setlength{\columnsep}{30pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.2pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter ]{Exercice}[1][]{
    enhanced,left=0pt,top=8pt,frame hidden,bottom=0pt,before upper={\hspace*{1cm}} ,colback=white,
    interior code app={\node[fill=col3, anchor=west,text width=0.5cm,text badly centered]at ([shift={(0.1,-0.5)}]frame.north west){{\large\color{white} \textbf{\centering\thetcbcounter}}};},nobeforeafter}
\begin{document}
\chap{Brownian motion}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
    \sect{Correlated Brownian motion.}
    \begin{Exercice}math math math math math math math math math math math math math math math
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\color{col3}\arabic*.}]
            \item math math math math
            \item math math math math
            \item math math math math
            \item math math math math
            \item math math math math
            \item math math math math
            \item math math math math
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{Exercice}
\begin{Exercice}math math math math math math math math math math math math math math math
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\color{col3}\arabic*.}]
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
\end{enumerate}
\end{Exercice}
    \sect{Correlated Brownian motion.}
\begin{Exercice}math math math math math math math math math math math math math math math
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\color{col3}\arabic*.}]
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
\end{enumerate}
\end{Exercice}
\begin{Exercice}math math math math math math math math math math math math math math math
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\color{col3}\arabic*.}]
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
\end{enumerate}
\end{Exercice}
\begin{Exercice}math math math math math math math math math math math math math math math
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\color{col3}\arabic*.}]
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
\end{enumerate}
\end{Exercice}
\begin{Exercice}math math math math math math math math math math math math math math math
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\color{col3}\arabic*.}]
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
\end{enumerate}
\end{Exercice}
\begin{Exercice}math math math math math math math math math math math math math math math
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\color{col3}\arabic*.}]
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
\end{enumerate}
\end{Exercice}
\begin{Exercice}math math math math math math math math math math math math math math math
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\color{col3}\arabic*.}]
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
\end{enumerate}
\end{Exercice}
\begin{Exercice}math math math math math math math math math math math math math math math
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\color{col3}\arabic*.}]
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
\end{enumerate}
\end{Exercice}
\begin{Exercice}math math math math math math math math math math math math math math math
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\color{col3}\arabic*.}]
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
\end{enumerate}
\end{Exercice}
\begin{Exercice}math math math math math math math math math math math math math math math
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\color{col3}\arabic*.}]
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
\end{enumerate}
\end{Exercice}
\begin{Exercice}math math math math math math math math math math math math math math math
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\color{col3}\arabic*.}]
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
\end{enumerate}
\end{Exercice}
\begin{Exercice}math math math math math math math math math math math math math math math
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\color{col3}\arabic*.}]
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
\end{enumerate}
\end{Exercice}
\begin{Exercice}math math math math math math math math math math math math math math math
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\color{col3}\arabic*.}]
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
\end{enumerate}
\end{Exercice}
\begin{Exercice}math math math math math math math math math math math math math math math
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\color{col3}\arabic*.}]
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
\end{enumerate}
\end{Exercice}
\begin{Exercice}math math math math math math math math math math math math math math math
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\color{col3}\arabic*.}]
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
    \item math math math math
\end{enumerate}
\end{Exercice}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The answer to the question "Create fascinating Math Homework Assignments" is IMHO "Ask something on number theory" because this is a truly fascinating subject. ;-) To get rid of the gap, it suffices to remove `\vskip1cm` at the end of `\newcommand{\chap}[1]{...`.

Comment: Thank youI fixed it. Yeah why not :)

Comment: _Is there any other package that can to create the same sheet That I created with TIKZ._ If this is an original creation of you I think the answer is no.

Comment: @vipa  I don't get your answer what do you mean by my original creation ? about the sheet or about the tikz package or this sheet do you see it on other place than here. could you elaborate please ?

Comment: The graphics of the sheet I mean. For package for create quiz sheet see for example [here](https://ctan.org/recommendations/verifica)

Comment: This one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369265/math-book-how-to-write-exercise-and-answers/371320#371320 could be an alternative to TikZ.