# Problems and solutions - in source code problem+solution together, in output first all the problems, and then all solutions. How to do it?

Tags: exercises, mathematics

I would like to write a mathbook with problems and solutions (first the problems, and then the solutions in the end). It should look somehow like this: [Math book: how to write Exercise and Answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369265/math-book-how-to-write-exercise-and-answers)

However, I would like to have a problem and its solution together in the LaTeX source code, probably use some command similiar to this:

```
\problem{text of the problem}{text of the solution of the problem}
```

Is this possible? Is there any enviroment for this?

Comment: Will each problem *always* be accompanied by a solution? How complex of a structure could the solution part be (in terms of LaTeX code)?

Comment: Yes, there will be a solution for each problem. Problems will have simple solutions, eg.  \problem{Solve 2x+3=5.}{1}.

Comment: There are the packages `xsim`, `exercise`, `answers`, `propsoln`, …