# Numbering exercise in a book

Tags: book-design, books

I would like to write exercise for each chapter in a documentclass of book as shown below:

```
Chapter 4

Blablabla 

Exercise 4.1. Blablablab

.....
.....

 Exercise 4.2. Blablablabla

....
....

 Chapter 5

 blablabla

 Exercise 5.1. Blablabla

 etc.
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exercises and https://ctan.org/topic/exercise should be helpful

Comment: Thanks @clemens. I tried but not much helpful.

Comment: You tried *all* of the packages https://ctan.org/topic/exercise ond *none* of it worked? I cannot believe that.

Comment: For example package `xsim` easily allows what you want. Or have a look at the `exercise` package. Or have a look at the solutions presented here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301/how-can-i-produce-exercises-in-one-part-of-a-latex-document-with-selected-answer?rq=1

Comment: it's possible to think of an exercise as similar to a non-italic theorem object.  with `amsthm` you could specify `\theoremstyle{definition} \newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}[chapter}` and then enter each exercise as `\begin{exercise} ... \end{exercise}`.  if you already have theorems in your book, that shouldn't be inconvenient.