# Un-collating content

Tags: table-of-contents

I have about 1000 math problems for my students. Each problem has a short answer, like `7`, and it will have a worked solution which will take the form of an image (of my handwriting etc.)

When I write the document, the source should have this structure:
problem
answer
worked solution

problem
answer
worked solution

...

The rendered PDF will have this structure:
problem
problem
...

solution
solution
...

worked solution
worked solution
...

How do I get this un-collating behaviour? Is there another word to describe this that I can research?

Comment: Have you tried the package designed for exercises and solutions, like [xsim](https://ctan.org/pkg/xsim?lang=en) or [exercise](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exercise/exercise.pdf)? I think they're both capable of doing what you ask, but I'm not that familiar with them myself.

Comment: This question seems related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/301/263192